# Solo Leveling a Huntress

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I'm currently just starting the game and leveling a Huntress.  She is 31 at the moment.  What are some good places to farm XP?  I can do Insane difficulty Deeper Well but it is somewhat boring doing run after run, so I would like to know other dungeons that yield good XP but are a little more challenging and engaging.  I have completed Alchemy Lab on Hard alone which was a a lot of fun, but quite a lot of time invested for not as much XP as I could get while doing Deeper Well runs.

This will have to be done solo so I'm not looking for the power leveling in ramparts with a lvl 70 friend.  I'm looking for the level with the moderate to best bang for my buck for XP but still pretty fun.

If Deeper Well is my best bet, what would be my second option, assuming it is more entertaining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I powerleveled my heroes with this guide. Quick-level your "tower squire" solo on first map (hard difficulty) to 20 and then switch to Ramparts- for leveling him to 60+. And you can setup squire defence @Ramparts and switch chars for leveling - its far more effective there. I tried to pwl huntress - without blocking its hard. and if you switch for squire blocking - why not use his deadlier towers

Answer (score 5):

The best way to solo level is to take advantage of the fact that you can swap heroes in between rounds.  Its hard for a huntress to solo effectively since she doesn't have any walls that can block off enemies.  I've found that the best way to solo is to make a tower squire and swap to whatever class I want for the experience after he's done building towers.

Deeper well xp doesn't really compare at all to later levels like glitterheim.  In the long term, swapping heros is much faster than grinding deeper wells to max level.